# if using cbc+hmac dealing with small size of data(less than 128bit) , will it cause any problem?

Tags: aes, hmac, cbc

if use AES-cbc,HMAC-SHA256, and there is some txt needed to be enc, and I divide this txt into small packages with variable length, then enc them. some of these package can be less than 128bit. Is this still secure? will it cause any problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the MAC'ing is done right (after the encryption) and if you pad the CBC data correctly there's no security risk. Howver changing to CTR or even better to GCM would be better, as both don't operate on whole blocks and GCM even provides authentication.